# Xcode crashes while adding RxDataSource to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift, rxdatasources

Hey I'm trying to get an UICollectionView, hosted by an UICollectionViewController working with RxCocoa and RxDataSources.

Everything works fine when I use an UIViewController, with an embedded UICollectionView.

But when I try to connect via the same logic:

```
        self.vm.sections
        .bind(to: self.collectionView!.rx.items(dataSource: self.vm.data))
        .disposed(by: self.bag)
```

with an UICollectionView inside an UICollectionViewController, Xcode crashes completely.

Is there something I'm missing about RxDataSources, that you cannot use them with UICollectionViewController?

Comment: This crashes Xcode 9.1 with a stack overflow. My guess is that when Xcode tries to show the stack trace from the crashed app, the trace is so deep that Xcode can't handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I have no idea about why Xcode crashes, it seems to be caused by RxCocoa's assertion checking.

The data source of `UICollectionViewController`'s `collectionView` is set by default.
How about setting it to `nil` before binding with observable?

```
self.collectionView!.dataSource = nil
self.vm.sections
.bind(to: self.collectionView!.rx.items(dataSource: self.vm.data))
.disposed(by: self.bag)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That actually worked. I deleted the DataSource in IB through deleting the Connection wich didn't work. But doing the same in Code is working.

Comment: Thanks for that! That's solved the issue with UITableViewController as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you inherit from UITableViewController you must call `tableView.datasource = nil` anytime you are doing a whole table reload or refresh action

Answer (score -1):

You should not use `UICollectionViewController` with `RxDataSource`

When use RxDatasource you must use `UIViewController` and create a UITableView or UICollectionView inside it.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah I guessed it should be that way from the Doc. But I'm experiencing right now a weird behavior with iOS 11 Large Title and an UIViewController with an UICollectionView inside

Comment: Hi, I would love to hear your opinion on why we shouldn't use `UICollectionViewController` or `UITableViewController` with `RxDataSources`. `UITableViewController` gives lots of good functionality that it's not so easy to implement on your own. I've found the accepted answer to solve the issue for me, and wonder what else could break by your comment.

Comment: @oronbz A few months ago when I was developing something with RxSwift I think it was mentioned that we should not use UICollectionViewController, But as the accepted answer suggested the right solution I think my answer is wrong